# Deserialize stream to object

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to stream returned from Amazon into an object.
Please see below.

```
Private Function GetReportData(ByVal service As MarketplaceWebServiceClient, ByVal merchantId As String, ByVal reportId As String) As String
    Dim request As New GetReportRequest()
    request.Merchant = merchantId
    request.ReportId = reportId
    request.Report = File.Open("report.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim data As String = Nothing

    Dim response As GetReportResponse = service.GetReport(request)

    Using reader = New StreamReader(request.Report, Encoding.UTF8)
        ' Do something with the value
        data = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    Return data

End Function
```

Here is some example data returned. There is no xml data.
It looks like this...

"sku fnsku asin product-name reserved_qty reserved_customerorders reserved_fc-transfers reserved_fc-processing
VPD-002 B22EMBMPAC B22EMBMPAC Product Name 3 0 3 0 
VPD-002 B22EMBMPAC B22EMBMPAC Product Name 3 0 3 0
VPD-002 B22EMBMPAC B22EMBMPAC Product Name 3 0 3 0
VPD-002 B22EMBMPAC B22EMBMPAC Product Name 3 0 3 0"

Is it possible to deserialize the stream to an object?

```
Public Class ReservedInventory
    Public Property sku As String
    Public Property fnsku As String
    Public Property asin As String
    Public Property product_name As String
    Public Property reserved_qty As Integer
    Public Property reserved_customerorders As Integer
    Public Property reserved_fc_transfers As Integer
    Public Property reserved_fc_processing As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: if space char is not a problem you can simple parse each line into a ReservedInventory object.

Comment: says c# but I don't see c#

Comment: yes you can deserialize to an object, but that is not valid json